# Gnome-shell stopped working after updating 11.10

Tags: 11.10, gnome, updates

I did a fresh install of ubuntu 11.10, then proceeded to install gnome-shell.

Worked wonderfully until I did a *sudo apt-get upgrade*...

Now logging into either GNOME or UNITY sessions, I am presented with login sounds and a blank nautilus desktop. No icons, no window manager, no panels, just my wallpaper.

Is there a way to diagnose the problem?

--UPDATE--

@Jorge: I'm able to use ALT+CTRL+DEL to bring up the logout dialog (no window manager) but PRNT SCRN does NOT respond with any screenshot dialog.

Here is an output of my [.xsession-errors](http://pastebin.com/aBhfa5Su)

Comment: Can you take a screenshot?

Comment: I ended up reinstalling ubuntu and doing the updates BEFORE installing gnome-shell,

Answer (score 2):

Your `sudo apt-get upgrade` may have crash while updating your packages, making your system unstable. You may want to try this :

```
sudo dpkg --configure -a
```

And this :

```
sudo apt-get install -f
```

You should probably update again your packages after that :

```
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade
```

And then restart.

If you still have the problem, check if any PPA that you have might cause the problem.

Comment: Thanks for the response, Nyamiou. Unfortunately no change. will busy checking repositories.

Comment: Reverting to original repos didn't seem to have any effect. looking at logs shows a lot of DBus errors regarding names not specified in .service files. not sure if it's related.